# MySQL insert into fails on particular fields

Tags: php, mysql

I believe that something in my code is stopping the PHP being inserted into the database which is strange because I use the same setup in other forms on the site which all parse successfully.

The thing which puzzles me the most is the fact that the form will go through successfully if only a `username` and `password` are specified, but when I try to add email (also a `varchar`) and a group (a 1 character integer), the form fails. I’ve added my code below so hopefully you would be able to help me find out what I'm doing wrong.

PHP:

```
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect('DOMAIN', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
if (!$link)
   { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db('DATABASE') or die('Could not select database');

// Convert form values to variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
$iemail = $_POST['email'];
$email = addslashes($iemail);
$group = $_POST['group'];

$order = "INSERT INTO `users` (name,pass,email,group)
VALUES ('$name','$pass', '$email', '$group')";

$result = mysql_query($result);
if($result)
{
echo 
header("Location: manageusers.php?result=success&name=$name");
die();
}
else
{
mysql_error();
}

mysql_close($link);
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Add User</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form" action="adduser.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Username</label>
                <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="e.g: John Smith" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pass">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" id="pass" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>'; ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="group">Group</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="group" id="group" required>
                <option value="1">Student</option>
                <option value="2">Teacher</option>
                <option value="0">Admin</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest error in your code is the actual `mysql_query` line:

```
$result = mysql_query($result);
```

So the query being run is `$result` (which is not even set) and the `$result` is the `$result` of the query `$result`? Shouldn’t that use `$order` instead like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($order);
```

And there are a few other issues with your code—including the use of a reserved MySQL name; `group`—so I have refactored your code to cover all bases. Including reworking your `mysql_*` calls to use `mysqli_*` instead since `mysql_*` is depreciated in PHP versions 5.3 to 5.4 and completely removed from PHP 5.5. Here it is. Notes below:

```
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysqli_connect('DOMAIN', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE') or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

// Set a '$_POST' array and roll through each value.
$post_array = array('name', 'pass', 'email', 'group');
foreach ($post_array as $post_key => $post_value) {
  $$post_value = isset($_POST[$post_value]) && !empty($_POST[$post_value]) ? $_POST[$post_value] : null;
}

// MD5 the password.
$pass = md5($pass);

// Unsure if you need to add slashes if you are using mysqli_stmt_bind_param.
// So including here if you need it. Just change the mysqli_stmt_bind_param to use $email_md5
$email_md5 = addslashes($email);

// Set the query.
$order = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `pass`, `email`, `group`)"
       . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
       ;

// Bind the params.
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($order, 'ssss', $name, $pass, $email, $group);
    
// Run the query.
$result = mysqli_query($link, $order) or die(mysqli_error());

if ($result) {
   header("Location: manageusers.php?result=success&name=$name");
}

// Free the result set.
mysqli_free_result($result);
    
// Close the connection.
mysqli_close($link);
```

Here is the breakdown of what I did:

- Your query line is this: `$result = mysql_query($result);` but shouldn’t that be `$result = mysqli_query($order);`? I rewrote that line for `mysqli_*` but that is the biggest error I found.
- I switched your code to use MySQLi extensions which is the preferred way of doing things now since `mysql_*` is depreciated in PHP versions 5.3 to 5.4 and completely removed from PHP 5.5.
- I also set a `$_POST` array so all of the post keys can be rolled through simply & have some basic validation using `isset` and `!empty`. Combing this with [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) gives you a lot more basic validation than your previous script had.
- You are attempting to insert into a table name `group` but `GROUP` is actually a MySQL reserved word that should not be used. And if it is used, it should be placed in back ticks like shown in my code.
- I am also using the command [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to actually bind the parameter to the query which is a simple way to prevent agains MySQL injections. Also using [`mysqli_free_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) and [`mysqli_close`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) to neatly close the MySQL process.
- Your code for the “success” makes no sense. You have an `echo` with nothing following it on one line, followed by `header(…);` call then followed by `die();`. I removed the `echo` as well as the `die()` since that is not technically wrong, but that is not really needed.

Answer (score 3):

group is a reserved keyword and you should avoid these words as the column names.
However if you want to use it wrap them in backticks

```
`group`
```

Checkout the complete list here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

> Most of the words in the table are forbidden by standard SQL as column
>   or table names (for example, GROUP). A few are reserved because MySQL
>   needs them and uses a yacc parser

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your solution and I've adjusted the name of the group column to al (accesslevel) but I am still getting an error and the data is still not being added.

Comment: what error you are getting and try to echo the query and see what you get.